# Why do I have to check "IF" ($_GET["$view"]) && $_GET("$view")! . What does "!" mean? Why does it equal = ""

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I can't understand that if sentence. Why can't I just check if $view is set? 2 more questions -What does "$_GET("$view")!" "!" sign mean there? What does ! change? Moreover, why does it equal = " "?

```
<?php
$myurl=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
  $view="";
 if(isset($_GET["$view"]) && $_GET("$view")! = "") { $view =$_GET["$view"];};
include(head.html);

switch($view] {

case "" :
 include(main.html);
break;

case "people" :
 include(people.html);
  break;
 case:"contact":
 include(contact.html);
 break;

 default :

    include(404.html);
    break;

};

include_once(foot.html;
?>
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you messed up your code. This will not execute, due to numerous errors. The `if` statement is probably

```
if(isset($_GET[$view]) && $_GET[$view] != "")
```

Ie, first check that the $view key exists, then check that key it is not empty. Note the difference between a key that does not exist, and a key that exist but is empty, and why you check for both in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I just check if $view is set?

Because apparently the author of that code didn't want the empty string to be valid. This will be the case if, say, there is a field called `$view` and the user does not put anything in it.

Actually, you could do that, since `$view` is initialized to the empty string anyway! This code was probably copy/pasted or written by a novice.

> What does ! change?

It's actually `!=`, written in a confusing way. These two are the same:

```
&& $_GET("$view")! = "")
&& $_GET("$view") != "")
```

Also, your code has a bug. `$_GET("$view")` is not valid, the `()` should be `[]`. So, here is the corrected and readable code:

```
if (isset($_GET["$view"]) && $_GET["$view"] != "") {
    $view = $_GET["$view"];
}
```

Also:

```
switch($view]           // ...what is this?
include_once(foot.html; // and this?
case:"contact":         // ummmm
```

Comment: @userNOID Yes, I pointed that out in my answer. That was an error in the original code.

Comment: Bottom include statement missing a bracket, and default case doesn't need `break;`. Wow, some code!

Comment: @MartyMcVry And an extra `:` in one of the `case`s, and absolutely horrible formatting :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$view="";
 if(isset($_GET["$view"]) && $_GET("$view")! = "") { $view =$_GET["$view"];};
```

You actually set `$view="";` as an empty parameter 
There for  `isset($_GET["$view"]` looks like this `isset($_GET[""]` 
You whole if statement with the above code is ignored

Likewise your `switch($view);` also looks like `switch("")`
This means only your first case will be executed no matter what you have in your `$_GET`

Check this portion of your code too for errors. the colon after case needs to be removed

```
case:"contact":
 include(contact.html);
 break;
```

Answer (score 0):

For first, use correctly [] and (). Then you have to learn about operators: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

For now your code is non-sense.